# Maintain Ordering Guarantees With Kafka Consumer Retries

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm in the process of coming up with an architecture for consumer retries in a Kafka based data processing pipeline. We're using Kafka producers and consumers and are thinking of retry topics on which messages will be sent if they error out on consumption. There will be consumers running on these retry topics at a certain cadence.

I read many reference architectures, but none talk about how to maintain ordering guarantees during message consumption failures. Let me give an example:

Our Kafka messages contain payload that has an object and an operation type (which could either be CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE). We partition messages on `object_id` to make sure that the operations on that object are ordered. However, if a message fails on consumption, should you automatically flag the subsequent messages with the same `object_id` as failed, without even attempting to process them? And how do you maintain that state?

Are there any reference architectures that address this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to have a mechanism in place wherein if one message with the same object_id fails and goes to retry, then all subsequent messages with the same object_id also go to retry directly.

I suggest to use a cache to co-ordinate this - whenever a message goes to retry, increment the object_id key. Similarly, whenever a message is successfully consumed from the retry topic, decrement the key.

Now, you need only check whether there exists a key with >0 value corresponding to the object_id before attempting to consume a message, and if it is, directly send it to retry.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple levels of retry topics, maintain distributed key-value cache, with key is `object_id` and value is level of retry topic.

On consumption of message check against this cache & if `object_id` is present then send event directly to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to have a blocking retry-policy here: i.e, not using retry-topics, but instead block on consumer (sleep the thread for some time), and then retry the same message. In this case you can guarantee the order always.
If you opt to use the retry-topic instead, you are gonna have a lot of headaches making sure the order is guaranteed.