# How can a Kafka consumer maintain strict ordering when errors occur?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

[Spring for Apache Kafka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) supports [non-blocking retries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic) using *retry topics*, with the important caveat that ordering guarantees are lost for retried messages.

Confluent describes a pattern for [maintaining the order of retried events](https://www.confluent.io/blog/error-handling-patterns-in-kafka/#pattern-4) by augmenting a retry topic with the new concept of a *redirect topic*.

Are there any reference implementations of this pattern, either open source (e.g., using `spring-kafka`) or on cloud vendors (e.g., Confluent, MSK)? Thanks!

Comment: See also this [related but more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51491659).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use non-blocking retries and retain strict ordering of records within a partition.

If you mean you want to maintain strict ordering within a subset of the partition contents (e.g. records with the same key). It is simpler to NOT use non-blocking retries and significantly increase the number of partitions so that other records within other partitions can be processed while reading from the failed partition is blocked.

Trying to retain strict ordering of a partition subset would be non-trivial.

Comment: [The pattern](https://www.confluent.io/blog/error-handling-patterns-in-kafka/#pattern-4) Confluent describes seems to address your last sentence, and it does indeed look non-trivial. My question was whether there are any reference implementations of that pattern (Spring Kafka or otherwise). Still, thanks for the advice about increasing the partition count. Marking this question as resolved based on that.